# EF Core 2.0 - Filtering data by user best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

There seem to be many ways to achieve this, but im trying to figure out what the best practice would be with .net Core 2 / EF core 2.0.

I have objects such as

```cs
public class Company {
    public Guid CompanyID {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
    ...
    public ICollection<UserLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }
}

public class Order {
    public Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
}

public class UserLocation {
    public Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

For my company Index page I only want companies that the user has access to to be displayed. Could a global filter be used for this or does that not work for this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if the user should not have access to the companies a global filter is a good solution. When the requirement only applies to the index page, you can best make a specific query for the index page.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I worded the question / example wrong I think. Yes I want to always filter those companies out based on the user. So I think I'll go down the global filter path, but struggle the best way to implement identity in the DBContext to allow the filter to work.